# On loop space of a product

Tags: loop-spaces

[consider good spaces so the objects and question make sense]

Who was the first to prove that the loop space of a product is homeomorphic to the product of the loop spaces? $$\Omega(X\times Y)\approx \Omega X\times \Omega Y$$

[any references are welcomed]

Comment: I don't really see the point of this question. The moment it occurs to you to talk about loop spaces this is one of the first things you could prove about them, and it doesn't particularly take any ingenuity to do so.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, I'm interested in historical proofs.

Comment: It is a corollary of whoever proved that a product of spaces is a categorical product.